# wildcard mapping support in openrasta 2.1?

Tags: openrasta

according to the answer to this question: [In OpenRasta, how do I configure a URI where I get "the remainder of the path" as a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699765/in-openrasta-how-do-i-configure-a-uri-where-i-get-the-remainder-of-the-path-a)
Openrasta should support wildcards in it's uri mapping, is this already supported in version 2.1?

thanks,

Rob

Comment: Question was answered by Sebastien Lambla in the openrasta newsgroup, see: http://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/2d3199692a2aac3b